# how to retrive value from one js file to another js file using ext js5

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here i have created combo using ext js5, here my issue is when user selected item from the combo, how can i retrieve selected item value from another js file.
here i am using the below code

```
Ext.define('app.view.panel.Add panel', { extend: 'Ext.container.Container',// alias: 'widget. Addpanel',
    xtype: 'app-add panel',
    cls: 'app-addpanel',
    title: false,
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
        'doscore.view.grids.Watchlist',
        'doscore.view.panel.AddpanelController',
        ],
    layout: 'hbox',
    reference: 'add-panel',
    hidden: true,
    itemId: 'add-panel',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        emptyText: 'Search for Company',
        // cls: 'qsearch-combo',
        width: '500',
        margin: '20 20 15 20',
        valueField: 'DataText',
        displayField: 'DataId',
        reference: 'source1',
        matchFieldWidth: false,
        listConfig: {
            listeners: {
                beforeshow: function(picker) {
                    picker.minWidth = picker.up('combobox').getSize().width;
                }
            }
        },
            listeners: {
    select: 'itemSelected'
            }
},
    {
      xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Add Company',
        margin: '20 20 15 10',
        select: 'itemSelected'
        }
    }
    ]
});
```

When user clicks any column, based on that name create tab and that column value to be passed to another ext js file. 
here js means not javascript it's ext js file.
Please share any information to me.

Answer (score 0):

query the combobox with an id or itemid,

```
comp = Ext.getCmp('<YOUR ID>');

comp.getValue() would be the column value you are looking for
```